# How to reduce the resolution of a dataArray using groupby_bins() on 2-coordinates (or any other way)

Tags: python, spatial, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a dataArray DIN such that:

```
xarray.DataArray 'DIN' (time: 1029 j: 180 i: 600)
[111132000 values with dtype=float32]

    Coordinates:
        latitude (j, i) [-8.074 -8.107 ... -28.56 -28.59]
        longitude (j, i) ...
        time (time) [2014-12-01T02:00:00 ... 2017-09-...]
    Attributes: (3)
```

I am trying to reduce the resolution of the coordinate system to reduce the size before converting it to a dataframe by taking the mean in a smaller grid. I have tried many methods, but the one that seems most promising is to use the `groupby_bins()`  function. I have created my desired bins (0.5x0.5 degree increments):

```
lat_bins = np.arange(DIN.latitude.min(), DIN.latitude.max() + 0.5, 0.5)
lon_bins = np.arange(DIN.longitude.min(),DIN.longitude.max() + 0.5, 0.5)
```

but am stuck as to how to pass that to the following function:

```
grouped = DIN.groupby_bins( **something goes here** , bins=?????).mean()
```

I am unsure how to convert these bins into a dataArray that is correctly formatted for the `groupby_bins()` function
Any pointers, or alternative methods would help.

Comment: Your coordinates are a bit whacky. You might want to convert them so that you do not have i and j but lat and lon directly. Also have a look at [`.coarsen()`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.DataArray.coarsen.html#xarray.DataArray.coarsen)